# Bounded solution for differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let x(t) a solution of the following differential inequality

$\frac{x'(t)}{1+{x(t)}^{2}}+x(t)f(t)<2f(t)$ ,   (1)

with $0\leq t\leq T$ , $\arctan(0)<\frac{\pi }{2}$ , $f(t)$ is a positive function and $x(t)\geq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Is the solution $x(t)$ bounded for all $T\geq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

$x(t)=-t$ is un unbounded solution of the differential inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I consider x(t) a positive function.

Comment: You should say so in the question.